# Rinkeby faucet needed in bulk but Faucets are not working

Tags: rinkeby, faucets

I am working on project i have to do minting in bulk for that I need many **Rinkeby Faucets**. Is there any way to get bulk faucets. Because https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby this link only provide 0.1 test eth and https://faucet.rinkeby.io/ is offline.

Comment: So first, with the Ethereum merge, Goerli is the only Ethereum testnet running. All others including Rinkeby have been deprecated.

If you do need any free Goerli testETH, here's a reliable faucet (there is a daily limit but I find it pretty much enough for all my daily projects) - https://goerlifaucet.com. In general, I find reliability is more of an issue than testETH limits, there's so much spam or subpar builds. 

Also if you're working on a project, this is good learning source for me - https://docs.alchemy.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use some discord channel for faucets. Some networks sometimes turn off faucet. stackexchange may not allow it, but you can reach it if you share your wallet address on the forums. I recommend using avaxfuji as testnet.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. Can you please share some useful discord links?

Comment: [CryptoDevs](https://discord.com/invite/5W5tVb3) This is the most active one, but you can contact more active developers on reddit. [reddit ethdev](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So first, with the Ethereum merge, Goerli is the only Ethereum testnet running. All others including Rinkeby have been deprecated.

If you do need any free Goerli testETH, here's a reliable faucet (there is a daily limit but I find it pretty much enough for all my daily projects) - goerlifaucet.com. In general, I find reliability is more of an issue than testETH limits, there's so much spam or subpar builds.

Also if you're working on a project, this is good learning source for me - docs.alchemy.com